# Vue unit testing - mocking imported services when using vue-test-utils mount

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2

I'm playing with mount() from vue-test-utils, have a component that imports services that should be mocked in the unit test.

I see that mount() has a mocks option, but trying to extrapolate the example given at [guides, common-tips, mocking injections](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/blob/dev/docs/en/guides/common-tips.md#mocking-injections) to the scenario of an injected service is eluding me.

```
mount(Component, {
  mocks: {
    ...?
  }
})
```

The component simply imports the service, which is plain JS

```
import DataService from '../services/data.service'
```

I can get it working using the inject-loader which is detailed here [Testing With Mocks](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/testing-with-mocks.html)

***The code that does work***

```
const MyComponentInjector = require('!!vue-loader?inject!./MyComponent.vue')
const mockedServices = {
  '../services/data.service': {
    checkAll: () => { return Promise.resolve() }
  },
}
const MyComponentWithMocks = MyComponentInjector(mockedServices)

const wrapper = mount(MyComponentWithMocks, { store: mockStore, router })
```

***What is the syntax for mount(MyComponent, { mocks: ... })?***

Since mount() has a mocks option, should it not be possible to pass mockedServices to it in some form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mocks` refers to the Vue instance. You're trying to mock a file dependency, which is a different problem. As you said, one solution is inject-loader. Another is the babel-plugin-rewire.

Let me clear up what the `mocks` option does.

`mocks` adds properties to the Vue instance.

If you have an app that injects `$route`, you might have a component that tries to access it: `this.$route.path`:

```
...
  methods: {
    logPath() {
      console.log(this.$route.path)
    }
  } 
...
```

If you try to `mount` this component without installing Vue router, it will throw an error. To solve this, you can use the `mocks` mount option to inject a mock `$route` object to the Vue instance:

```
const $route = { path: 'some/mock/value' }
mount(Component, {
  mocks: {
    $route
  }
})
```

Comment: Cheers Edd, I saw from **add-mocks.js** that the mocks options just adds properties to the instance. Coming from Angular where injected dependencies **do** end up as instance properties, I was thinking the same for Vue. Purely as an experiment, I set up my service as an instance property with `created () { this.dataService = DataService }`. I could then mock it without the injector, but not in mount's mocks option, I had to replace it on wrapper.vm after mount. I guess from that the injector is running after add-mocks runs.

Comment: Yep, the mocks run before we create an instance

Comment: A further note, the documented way of mocking with injector doesn't quite feel right (multiple steps, injection key is a path string rather than a dependency name). Adding [vue-inject](https://github.com/jpex-js/vue-inject) to the project makes mocking services easier.

Comment: So, just to be clear: vue-test-utils does *not* support mock injection out of the box? It looks like only the long form works with inject loader, is that correct?