# How to mock a Vuex store in VueJS test-utils parentComponent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm using `Jest` with `vue-test-utils` trying to test if a child component reacts to an `$emit` event in the parent component.

VueJS test-utils library provides a `parentComponent` option to be passed when mounting/shallow mounting the component.

Everything is working fine except that even though I instantiate the component with a mocked Vuex store, the parent component throws a

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

on a `this.$store.state.something.here` piece of code in the parent component.

How can I mock the Vuex store there?

The component mount looks like this:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(ChildComponent, {
  store,
  localVue,
  parentComponent: ParentComponent,
  mocks: {
    $t: msg => msg,
  },
});
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

it may not be the complete answer to OP questions, but since I had been debugging around for the last 2h and finally found MY problem, I would like to posted here to help someone in the future.

I was trying to mock and mount the following component:

```
<template>
<div test="object-list-div">
  <h1 test="component-title">{{ objectName }}</h1>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr test="table-row-title">
            <th scope="col" test="table-column-title" v-for="(value, name, index) in objectData[0]" :key="index">{{ name }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr test="table-row-data" v-for="(ivalue, iname, i) in objectData" :key="i">
        <td test="table-cell-data" v-for="(jvalue, jname, j) in ivalue" :key="j">{{ jvalue }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
export default  {

    props: [
        'objectName',
        'objectData'
    ],
    computed: {
      visibleColums() {
        return this.$store.state.Config_ShowColumn;
      }
    }
}
```

with the following wrapper code

```
 wrapper = shallowMount(ObjectList, {
    mocks: {
      $store: {
        state: {
          Config_ShowColumn: [
            "Field1",
            "Field2",
            "Field3",
            "Field4",
            "Field5",
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

I got OP error, but in my case the component **was expecting two Props** at the moment of creation. Since it did not receive this, it got stuck.

This is working now:

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { expect } from "chai";
import ObjectList from "@/components/Object-List.vue";  

wrapper = shallowMount(ObjectList, {
    propsData: {
      objectName: "Ticket",
      objectData: [
        {
          Field1: "Field1",
          Field2: "Field2",
          Field3: "Field3",
          Field4: "Field4",
          Field5: "Field5",
        },
      ]
    }, 
    mocks: {
      $store: {
        state: {
          Config_ShowColumn: [
            "Field1",
            "Field2",
            "Field3",
            "Field4",
            "Field5",
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Tried the solution Richard proposed but without much success, even though his guess was right.

The solution was far simnpler than I envisioned, I just stopped instantiating the Vuex.Store and just have the mocked `$store` in `vue-test-utils` `config` like so:

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount, config } from '@vue/test-utils';

config.mocks.$store = {
  state: {
    user: {
      sexy: true
    },
  },
};
```

I had no need to use an actual instance of Vuex as I only needed to mock the actual data so this worked perfectly.

Comment: Indeed, that works too. See [Vue unit testing - mocking imported services when using vue-test-utils mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553779/vue-unit-testing-mocking-imported-services-when-using-vue-test-utils-mount/46559540#46559540). Edd says >mocks adds properties to the Vue instance.

Answer (score 2):

How are you creating the mock store? It should be something like

```js
const storeOptions = {
  state: {...},
  getters: {...},
  mutations: {...}
}
const mockStore = new Vuex.Store(storeOptions)
```

Since `this.$store` is undefined, I suspect you might just be passing the options object to shallowMount.